# Rejecting registerization due to ushr-int , what does it mean?

Tags: android, dalvik

I got following in logcat:

```
03-06 22:53:33.859: D/dalvikvm(13350): Rejecting registerization due to ushr-int/lit8 v4, v7, (#19)
```

But it didn't stop the flow of the application.

I just want to know why this is appearing, searched a lot about this but found nothing other than description of this opcode `ushr-int/lit8 v4, v7` , which is:

```
Unsigned right shift of v0 (>>>) by the bit positions specified by the literal constant and put the result into vx.
```

But it doesn't explain about the `Rejecting Registerization`.

[Dalvik opcodes](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html)

Comment: I don't see the term "registerization" anywhere in the dalvik codebase. It's possible this is due to some OEM customization or something